# How to not escape form body characters in Spring RestTemplate when making a POST request?

Tags: spring, http, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have following code where I am making a POST form request. The request body contains username and password. Password contains @ characters, which is replaced by RestTemplate with %40 and I am getting "unauthorized" error as the password is wrong now.
Following is the debug info from bufferOutput(request body)

```
merchant_id=firstname+de-lastname%40gmail.com&password=%40Password
```

Here is the code snippet that is making the call.

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
String url = "SOME_URL";
formData.add("username", "xay@gmail.com");
formData.add("password", "@name321");

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>>(formData,headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
                .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Authentication.class,"321");
```

**The question is how to tell restTemplate not to escape body data ?**
Note that the request has to be a post form request and I can not use UriComponentsBuilder to fix the problem.

Comment: where is your rest template call?

Comment: add the missing call

Comment: Is your URL encoded??

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a [FormHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html) to your RestTemplate rather than a StringHttpMessageConverter.